# Passing as Generics Keys of Extending Class

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a BaseEntity with generic `get` and `set` methods that will inherit their keys from the extending classes and I'm getting the following error:
`Type 'IBaseModel' recursively references itself as a base type.`

Minimal repro of the issue

```
type IBaseEntityKeys = keyof Omit<IBaseEntity, keyof EventTarget>;

class IBaseEntity extends EventTarget {
  id!: string;
  locked!: boolean;
  namespace!: string;
  protected readonly logPrefix!: string;

  constructor(logPrefix: string) {
    super();
    this.logPrefix = logPrefix;
  }

  override addEventListener(
    type: IBaseEntityKeys,
    callback: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject | null,
    options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined
  ): void {
    super.addEventListener(type, callback, options);
  }
}

export class BaseEntity<T = any> extends IBaseEntity {
  constructor(options: any) {
    super(options.logPrefix ?? '');
    this.id = options.id;
    this.locked = !!options.locked;
    this.namespace = options.namespace ?? 'default';
  }

  get(key: IBaseEntityKeys) {
    return this[key];
  }

  set<K extends IBaseEntityKeys>(key: K, value: IBaseEntity[K]) {
    (this as IBaseEntity)[key] = value;
  }
}

type IBaseModelKeys = keyof Omit<
  IBaseModel,
  keyof EventTarget | 'get' | 'set' | 'doClone' | 'clone'
>;

class IBaseModel extends BaseEntity<IBaseModelKeys> {
  parent!: IBaseModel;
  selected!: boolean;
  hovered!: boolean;
  painted!: boolean;
}

export class BaseModel extends IBaseModel {
  constructor(options: any) {
    super({ namespace: 'default', ...options });

    this.parent = options.parent;
    this.selected = false;
    this.hovered = false;
    this.painted = false;
  }
}
```

I found some issues and guides when wandering around the web, such as https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40315
and still didn't manage to work around this issue.
I'm using TS version 4.9.5
Any guidance or help in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code to be a self-contained single-file [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we paste it into our own IDEs, so that it's easy for us to get working on it immediately without needing to try to get it set up.

Comment: @jcalz added minimal reproducible.

Comment: Your `BaseEntity` class is completely independent of its type parameter; it doesn't use `T` at all.  So the obvious approach is to remove the type parameter and the circularity goes away.  Since I imagine that's not acceptable, then this doesn't look like a [mre] of your actual issue.  Could you fix it so there's some purpose to `T`?  Otherwise my only suggestion here, if you have to keep `T`, is to break the circularity by adding redundant key names and checking them later, as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/wRBvvw).  There *might* be something better, but if `T` is being thrown out I don't know.

Comment: Don't overthink your problem. [Here](https://tsplay.dev/m3x9jW) a working solution. If you don't understand it or you need further explanation I'll will write up a solution.

Comment: @jcalz, the reason for T is I want to infer T's keys as part of the construction for the base class, to allow intelli sense and type check when using methods like `addEventListener`, `get`, `set`.
@Filly you solution is almost there, that is what I started with, but if you check the auto-completion on the playground, you can see it resolves properties such as the `get` and `set`, and that's the reason I try to Omit specific properties and dynamically infer the keys, from the inheriting class all the way down to the base class.